# User Defaults Won't Instantiate View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, appdelegate, userdefaults

When a user logs into my app, a Swift UserDefault is saved for the key "isLogged" and set to the true. My goal is to have the app delegate show a different view controller if the value of this UserDefault is true.

I've been struggling for weeks to get this running and thus wanted to see if anyone knew any issues. I'm calling a function in my AppDelegate.swift to instantiate the view controller, but for some reason the view controller is never shown. The print statement is executed, so I know the value is being set, but why is the view controller not being shown?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  checkDefault()

  return true
}

func checkDefault() {
   if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogged") == true) {
     print("LoggedIn is true")
     let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:  
     Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
     "parent_vc") as! ParentHomeViewController

     let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
     let share = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
     share?.window?.rootViewController = navVC
     share?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not change the view controller hierarchy? Have ApDelegate instantiate a **single** VC - like it usually does - and have *that* root VC instantiate what it needs to?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: please share what you get in debugger window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your `checkDefault()` in `SceneDelegate.swift` .

to be exact you have to call the func  in,

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
```

For further reading and understanding, you can use this
https://medium.com/@kalyan.parise/understanding-scene-delegate-app-delegate-7503d48c5445
for reference.

Comment: Hey Vivek, thanks for your response! I put the function in the SceneDelegate, but when the app is opened it takes me to a black screen. I think maybe the code is working, but for some reason it's not getting the view controller I want

Comment: @astroworld85 can you try the code in the below way                                                   `let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Controller)
            navVC.navigationBar.isHidden = true
            navVC.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = Controller as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
            navVC.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code & Its Working fine.

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

 let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "parent_vc") as! ParentHomeViewController

 let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
 self.window?.rootViewController = navVC
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dhruvin! I put in your revised code, yet the view controller still isn't instantiated.